# Apache FilesMatch

Tags: apache

With Apache, I can target files by extension like this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|png|js|css)$">
```

Can you also target specific files by their entire filename. For example "bg.jpg":

```
<FilesMatch "bg.jpg">
```

Would that work?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Should be moved to ServerFault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a regular expression, which means you should anchor it with a caret "^" in front and a dollar sign "$" at the end. Plus escape the dot, as joschi said.

Comment: In CakePHP 1.3 FilesMatch does not affect files in themed webroot! I don't know why?! For more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927604/leverage-browser-caching-and-cakephp

Comment: the "should" portion of this answer might make encourage readers to use anchors without really knowing why. here are some examples with explanations...  
  
`bd.jpg` (anywhere, loose match [unescaped dot matches any single character])  
`bg\.jpg` (anywhere, exact match)  
`^bg\.jpg` (starts with)  
`^bg\.jpg$` (exact match)  
`bg\.jpg$` (ends with)  
  
hope that helps those new to regex 

Comment: The question was how to "target specific files by their entire filename", and my answer was in that context only.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that will work but you need to escape the dot (`\.`) if you want to use [FilesMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch). You could also simply use [Files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files).