# Leverage Browser Caching and CakePHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, caching, cakephp-1.3

I asked my host if they supports mod_expires or not, they told me that it is supported. I use CakePHP and I tried the following code in `webroot/.htaccess` and `app_root/.htaccess but Google's page speed is stile considering there is issue in caching of css, js, png, jpg, etc. it found them 24 hour! *as the screenshot shows below*

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31449600, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

The above code is adopted from [this article](http://www.chicagostyleseo.com/2010/04/googles-need-for-speed-use-cache-and-htaccess-to-speed-up-your-site/).

Also I used the following:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
# ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 year"
# ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
# ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
 ExpiresDefault "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Also I tried to use both codes with each other but the Google Speed tell me the same. Look at the following screen shot:

[image]

**I need to know how could I solve this issue?!!**

> ### Edit##
>
> Using firebug in Firefox I noticed that only resources in the `app/views/themed/slate/webroot` are not be affected with the cache
>   settings regarded above, but those found directly in `app/webroot` ,
>   i.e without, theming are affected well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be [a bug in cakephp](https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/tickets/4095-htaccess-settings-for-cache-and-themed-views-issue). In cakePHP 1.3+ the themed view assets have been moved from `app/webroot/themed/themeTitle` to `app/views/themed/themeTitle/webroot`.

According to [CakePHP 1.3 documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Views.html#themes) you are able to restore the old place (i.e. in the main webroot) of the themed static assets by creating `app/webroot/theme/themeTitle`

> Linking to static assets is slightly different from 1.2. You can still
>   use the existing app/webroot/themed and directly link to those static
>   files. It should be noted that you will need to use the full path to
>   link to assets in app/webroot/themed. If you want to keep your theme
>   assets inside app/webroot it is recommended that you **rename
>   app/webroot/themed to app/webroot/theme**. This will allow you to
>   leverage the core helper path finding. As well as keep the performance
>   benefits of not serving assets through PHP.

So, what I have done for solve this issue is to copying all files in `app/views/themed/slate/webroot` to `app/webroot/theme/slate`

The following screen shot is from FireFox Firebug that shows an image file get the expire after one year in seconds:

[image]