# CakePHP Google PageSpeed Insights Leverage browser caching

Tags: performance, .htaccess, cakephp, caching

I'm using CakePHP 2.6 and at this moment i'm trying to fix Google PageSpeed warnings, i'm stuck on this one:

> Leverage browser caching
>   Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources >instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk >rather than over the network.

This is my app/webroot/.htaccess file at the moment

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
     # compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
     # Or, compress certain file types by extension:
     <files *.html>
         SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
     </files>
     <files *.ctp>
         SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
     </files>
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/x-ico "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 24 hours"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching

> We recommend a minimum cache time of one week and preferably up to one year for static assets, or assets that change infrequently.

So try increasing the expiry time from "access plus 24 hours" to "access plus 1 week".

Comment: After i update the .htaccess to "access plus 1 week" i'm still getting the information from Google Pagespeed that it's set to 24 hours. I have a found a different question with the same problem, but no solution. Since they're talking about version 1.2 and i'm on 2.6 don't know if the problem still persists http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927604/leverage-browser-caching-and-cakephp

Comment: CakePHP version is irrelevant since you setting the expiry values through htaccess.